# How do i pass an of object or string using React native share API

Tags: reactjs, api, react-native, share, native

```
onShare(Name) {
  Share.share({
     title: 'Logs', 
     message: Name
   },{
     dialogTitle: 'Sending log messages'
  });
}
```

When i try to put in data it says 'atleast one message is required'
How do I pass an object or a variable into message?

Comment: what is that `Name` contains? What kind of information?

Comment: name contains a string